# onUpdateFrame does not scan small image

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am working on a an ar application where I have to place ring(ar object) in finger.I am following an augmented image example from codelabs but when I change the image in the project and scan the same image(small image)placed on my finger it does not detected,onUpdateFrame does not gets called.But when I scan the same image added in the project it places an object.So I would like to know whether this scenario can be achieved from augmented image concept or am I making some mistake?